Docker container returns SSL error when connecting to OpenAI API despite installing ca-certificates
I'm running a backend service in a Docker container, and I am facing an SSL error while trying to connect to an external API. The error I'm getting is:
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='openaipublic.blob.core.windows.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /encodings/cl100k_base.tiktoken (Caused by SSLError(SSLZeroReturnError(6, 'TLS/SSL connection has been closed (EOF) (_ssl.c:1147)')))
To troubleshoot, I've already tried updating my Dockerfile to include the following:
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y ca-certificates

However, I'm still getting the same SSL error. Here are some additional details:

I'm using Python and the requests library to make HTTPS requests.
My Dockerfile is based on the official Python image.
The backend works fine when running directly on my local machine, but the error appears when running in Docker.

I've also tried a number of other suggestions I've seen, including:

Updating openssl in the Docker container.
Ensuring certifi is up to date in Python.
Adding RUN apt-get install -y openssl to the Dockerfile.

But none of these steps have solved the problem.
Does anyone have ideas on what could be causing this SSL error, and how I might fix it in the Docker environment? Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Dockerfile snippet:
FROM python:3.9

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]

Docker Compose Snippet:
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000-3002:3000"
    expose:
      - "3000"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3

  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - OPENAI_API_KEY=${OPENAI_API_KEY}
    volumes:
      - ./backend/data:/app/data
    ports:
      - "8000-8002:8000"
    expose:
      - "8000"
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
  
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro
    depends_on:
      - frontend
      - backend

Note: It works fine outside Docker, which makes me think there's something related to the container environment, but I can't pinpoint what exactly.

It works fine hitting the host with curl  *  SSL certificate verify ok.. So from the OS level it seems ok
